r evaluate column of strings to determine if contain characters found in a vecto
I have a data frame with variable that contains strings
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
string = c("blah, F21, blah",
     "woop, woop, F25",
     "G1, yes, yes",
     "hey, hey F23",
     "how, G2, how"))

I have a vector that contains a list of characters that I want to use to search thru my dataframe
check <- c("F21", "F23", "G1")

I am looking for help on trying to evaluate the string variable to determine if it contains any characters that are in the check vector.  I would like the output df to look like this



ID
string
test




1
blah, F21, blah
in check


2
woop, woop, F25
not in check


3
G1, yada, yada
in check


4
hey, hey, F23
in check


5
how, G2, how
not in check



A Tidyverse would be very much appreciated.
the struggle bus is camped out in my driveway

You could form a regex alternation of your check substrings, and then use grepl() to check for their presence in the data frame:
check <- c("F21", "F23", "G1")
regex <- paste0("\\b(?:", paste(check, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
df$test <- ifelse(grepl(regex, df$string), "in check", "not in check")
df

  ID          string         test
1  1 blah, F21, blah     in check
2  2 woop, woop, F25 not in check
3  3    G1, yes, yes     in check
4  4    hey, hey F23     in check
5  5    how, G2, how not in check

Note: If your actual intention be to find the patterns as any substrings (but not as standalone words), then use this regex pattern instead:
regex <- paste0("(?:", paste(check, collapse="|"), ")")


And iff, as is also likely, which 'check' is 'in'  check...or does this extend to this interest?

Thank you so much, this worked perfectly.

@ScottPurvis Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.
